# How to call another components function in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I have two components as follows and I want to call a function from another component. Both components are included in the third parent component using directive.

Component 1:

```js
@component(
    selector:'com1'
)
export class com1{
    function1(){...}
}
```

Component 2:

```js
@component(
    selector:'com2'
)
export class com2{
    function2(){...
        // i want to call function 1 from com1 here
    }
}
```

I've tried using `@input` and `@output` but I don't understand exactly how to use it and how to call that function, can anyone help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50739783/5043867

Answer (score 164, accepted):

If com1 and com2 are siblings you can use

```ts
@component({
  selector:'com1',
})
export class com1{
  function1(){...}
}
```

com2 emits an event using an `EventEmitter`

```ts
@component({
  selector:'com2',
  template: `<button (click)="function2()">click</button>`
)
export class com2{
  @Output() myEvent = new EventEmitter();
  function2(){...
    this.myEvent.emit(null)
  }
}
```

Here the parent component adds an event binding to listen to `myEvent` events and then calls `com1.function1()` when such an event happens.
`#com1` is a template variable that allows to refer to this element from elsewhere in the template. We use this to make `function1()` the event handler for `myEvent` of `com2`:

```ts
@component({
  selector:'parent',
  template: `<com1 #com1></com1><com2 (myEvent)="com1.function1()"></com2>`
)
export class com2{
}
```

For other options to communicate between components see also [component-interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: Your question doesn't contain anything about parent-child. What do you try to accomplish?

Comment: when you started saying "Here the parent component adds an event binding to listen to myEvent", I'm very confused. I thought we are trying to solve the sibling component situation. The angular link is all parent child, so I can't use those.

Comment: It's the parent of rhe siblings (you can also say host). `<sibling1 (myEvent)="...">` is an event binding for the parent/host, because that's the only way Angular provides. The event handler however calls a method on the other sibling (`com1`). The parent is used as a mediator.

Comment: How to call it out of the view?! Just inside the `somecomponent.ts`?

Comment: But if two different component(On Click event((one component)) for some user in list & copy that click event on detail page(another component) ) - From One Component method I want to use in another component, how to do that Please tell me ??? @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: @JigneshVagh sorry, but I don't understand what you try to accomplish. I'd suggest you create a new question with your code that demonstrates what what you try to accomplish.

Comment: And if I need to pass parameters with the event emitter? Something like com1.function(parameter)

Comment: @MatheusBernardi you can do that.

Comment: Good explanation..!

Answer (score 448):

First, what you need to understand the relationships between components. Then you can choose the right method of communication. I will try to explain all the methods that I know and use in my practice for communication between components.

What kinds of relationships between components can there be?

**1. Parent > Child**

[image]

***Sharing Data via Input***

This is probably the most common method of sharing data. It works by using the `@Input()` decorator to allow data to be passed via the template.

*parent.component.ts*

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `
    <child-component [childProperty]="parentProperty"></child-component>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent{
  parentProperty = "I come from parent"
  constructor() { }
}
```

*child.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
      Hi {{ childProperty }}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() childProperty: string;

  constructor() { }

}
```

This is a very simple method. It is easy to use. We can also catch changes to the data in the child component using [ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges).

But do not forget that if we use an object as data and change the parameters of this object, the reference to it will not change. Therefore, if we want to receive a modified object in a child component, it must be immutable.

**2. Child > Parent**

[image]

***Sharing Data via ViewChild***

[ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) allows one component to be injected into another, giving the parent access to its attributes and functions. One caveat, however, is that `child` won’t be available until after the view has been initialized. This means we need to implement the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook to receive the data from the child.

*parent.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from "../child/child.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `
    Message: {{ message }}
    <child-compnent></child-compnent>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child;

  constructor() { }

  message:string;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.message = this.child.message
  }
}
```

*child.component.ts*

```js
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {

  message = 'Hello!';

  constructor() { }

}
```

***Sharing Data via Output() and EventEmitter***

Another way to share data is to emit data from the child, which can be listed by the parent. This approach is ideal when you want to share data changes that occur on things like button clicks, form entries, and other user events.

*parent.component.ts*

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `
    Message: {{message}}
    <child-component (messageEvent)="receiveMessage($event)"></child-component>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent {

  constructor() { }

  message:string;

  receiveMessage($event) {
    this.message = $event
  }
}
```

*child.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
      <button (click)="sendMessage()">Send Message</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {

  message: string = "Hello!"

  @Output() messageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() { }

  sendMessage() {
    this.messageEvent.emit(this.message)
  }
}
```

**3. Siblings**

[image]

***Child > Parent > Child***

I try to explain other ways to communicate between siblings below. But you could already understand one of the ways of understanding the above methods.

*parent.component.ts*

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `
    Message: {{message}}
    <child-one-component (messageEvent)="receiveMessage($event)"></child1-component>
    <child-two-component [childMessage]="message"></child2-component>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent {

  constructor() { }

  message: string;

  receiveMessage($event) {
    this.message = $event
  }
}
```

*child-one.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-one-component',
  template: `
      <button (click)="sendMessage()">Send Message</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./child-one.component.css']
})
export class ChildOneComponent {

  message: string = "Hello!"

  @Output() messageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() { }

  sendMessage() {
    this.messageEvent.emit(this.message)
  }
}
```

*child-two.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-two-component',
  template: `
       {{ message }}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./child-two.component.css']
})
export class ChildTwoComponent {

  @Input() childMessage: string;

  constructor() { }

}
```

**4. Unrelated Components**

[image]

All the methods that I have described below can be used for all the above options for the relationship between the components. But each has its own advantages and disadvantages.

**Sharing Data with a Service**

When passing data between components that lack a direct connection, such as siblings, grandchildren, etc, you should be using a shared service. When you have data that should always be in sync, I find the RxJS BehaviorSubject very useful in this situation.

*data.service.ts*

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

*first.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'first-componennt',
  template: `
    {{message}}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./first.component.css']
})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) {
      // The approach in Angular 6 is to declare in constructor
      this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

}
```

second.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'second-component',
  template: `
    {{message}}
    <button (click)="newMessage()">New Message</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./second.component.css']
})
export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

  newMessage() {
    this.data.changeMessage("Hello from Second Component")
  }

}
```

***Sharing Data with a Route***

Sometimes you need not only pass simple data between component but save some state of the page. For example, we want to save some filter in the online market and then copy this link and send to a friend. And we expect it to open the page in the same state as us. The first, and probably the quickest, way to do this would be to use [query parameters](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters).

Query parameters look more along the lines of `/people?id=` where `id` can equal anything and you can have as many parameters as you want. The query parameters would be separated by the ampersand character.

When working with query parameters, you don’t need to define them in your routes file, and they can be named parameters. For example, take the following code:

*page1.component.ts*

```js
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {Router, NavigationExtras} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: "page1",
  template: `
    <button (click)="onTap()">Navigate to page2</button>
  `,
})
export class Page1Component {

    public constructor(private router: Router) { }

    public onTap() {
        let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
            queryParams: {
                "firstname": "Nic",
                "lastname": "Raboy"
            }
        };
        this.router.navigate(["page2"], navigationExtras);
    }

}
```

In the receiving page, you would receive these query parameters like the following:

*page2.component.ts*

```js
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: "page2",
    template: `
         <span>{{firstname}}</span>
         <span>{{lastname}}</span>
      `,
})
export class Page2Component {

    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;

    public constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            this.firstname = params["firstname"];
            this.lastname = params["lastname"];
        });
    }

}
```

***NgRx***

The last way, which is more complicated but more powerful, is to use [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/). This library is not for data sharing; it is a powerful state management library. I can't in a short example explain how to use it, but you can go to the official site and read the documentation about it.

To me, NgRx Store solves multiple issues. For example, when you have to deal with observables and when responsibility for some observable data is shared between different components, the store actions and reducer ensure that data modifications will always be performed "the right way".

It also provides a reliable solution for HTTP requests caching. You will be able to store the requests and their responses so that you can verify that the request you're making does not have a stored response yet.

You can read about NgRx and understand whether you need it in your app or not:

- [Angular Service Layers: Redux, RxJs and Ngrx Store - When to Use a Store And Why?](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-redux-ngrx-rxjs/)
- [Ngrx Store - An Architecture Guide](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ngrx-store-and-effects-crash-course/)

Finally, I want to say that before choosing some of the methods for sharing data you need to understand how this data will be used in the future. I mean maybe just now you can use just an `@Input` decorator for sharing a username and surname. Then you will add a new component or new module (for example, an admin panel) which needs more information about the user. This means that may be a better way to use a service for user data or some other way to share data. You need to think about it more before you start implementing data sharing.

Comment: in 3. Siblings the ts child-two.component.ts display name in html should be childMessage (for the case use html file)

Comment: is there a reference for this comment " The approach in Angular 6 is to declare in constructor" and why it is recommended rather than moving it into `NgOnInit`

Answer (score 125):

You can access component one's method from component two..

**componentOne**

```js
  ngOnInit() {}

  public testCall(){
    alert("I am here..");    
  }
```

**componentTwo**

```js
import { oneComponent } from '../one.component';


@Component({
  providers:[oneComponent ],
  selector: 'app-two',
  templateUrl: ...
}


constructor(private comp: oneComponent ) { }

public callMe(): void {
    this.comp.testCall();
  }
```

*componentTwo html file*

```js
<button (click)="callMe()">click</button>
```

Comment: This was it for me until I needed to for instance access a variable in componentOne from componentTwo by invoking testCall.... the case for which the variable value is set by componentOne but componentTwo will get the default and not the current.

Comment: I am not getting componentOne variable values inside to the testCall method if i call testCall from componentTwo. Any idea?

Comment: Please explain this method for Ionic 4 with Angular 7

Comment: with this way it does not triger @Raja having the same problem

Comment: This is worst way to solve problem because of these reasons : (1) It causes circular dependency problem every time you run npm run build/start (2) You need to provide providers in component level (3) if you are doing data based operation in different components by sharing methods, this way is not going to work. Alternatives : use event emitter to pass data between two components and handle from methods appropriately and if its possible share method from a service.

Comment: Simply injected it in and call it worked well for me.

Answer (score 49):

Component 1(child):

```js
@Component(
  selector:'com1'
)
export class Component1{
  function1(){...}
}
```

Component 2(parent):

```js
@Component(
  selector:'com2',
  template: `<com1 #component1></com1>`
)
export class Component2{
  @ViewChild("component1") component1: Component1;

  function2(){
    this.component1.function1();
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, see also [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild).

Comment: all right how i call function2 on html? i always got this.component1 is undefined

Comment: <com1 #component1 (click)="function2()"></com1>

Comment: This worked for me, once i realized that you had to import ViewChild from @angular/core and also Component1 from wherever it is.

Comment: @IhorKhomiak I have used the same solution for one of my problems but I see the error TS2339: Property 'X' does not exist on type 'Y', 'X' being the method defined in the component 'Y'. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: I guess you need to check row with @ViewChild(...). There should be the exact type of your component: @ViewChild("component1") component1: Component1; And not ElementRef type.  Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Instead of extending the component class, i uesd `@ViewChild` which worked for me. Thanks for this example.

Answer (score 29):

It depends on the relation between your components (parent / child) but the best / generic way to make communicate components is to use a shared service.

See this doc for more details:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

That being said, you could use the following to provide an instance of the com1 into com2:

```html
<div>
  <com1 #com1>...</com1>
  <com2 [com1ref]="com1">...</com2>
</div>
```

In com2, you can use the following:

```js
@Component({
  selector:'com2'
})
export class com2{
  @Input()
  com1ref:com1;

  function2(){
    // i want to call function 1 from com1 here
    this.com1ref.function1();
  }
}
```

Comment: i am getting error Can't bind to 'com1Ref' since it isn't a known native property

Comment: and its not taking this.com1.function1(); instead this.com1ref.function1();

Comment: Thanks for pointing the typo out! Do you have the `@Input` on the field?

Comment: ok its working , can you tell me how to achieve same for parent - child relation??

Comment: i tried same for parent child but it says function1() of undegined

Answer (score 5):

Using Dataservice we can call the function from another component

Component1: The component which we are calling the function

```
constructor( public bookmarkRoot: dataService ) { } 

onClick(){
     this.bookmarkRoot.callToggle.next( true );
}
```

dataservice.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class dataService {
     callToggle = new Subject();
}
```

Component2:The component which contains the function

```
constructor( public bookmarkRoot: dataService ) { 
  this.bookmarkRoot.callToggle.subscribe(( data ) => {
            this.closeDrawer();
        } )
} 

 closeDrawer() {
        console.log("this is called")
    }
```

Comment: this may call multiple times to avoid that use this code inside constructor `if ( this.bookmarkRoot.callToggle.observers.length === 0 ) {
            this.bookmarkRoot.callToggle.subscribe(( data ) => {
                this.closeDrawer();
            } )
        }`

Comment: you may want to use a pipeable operator such as  `this.bookmarkRoot.callToggle.pipe(skipWhile(data=>data.length !==0).subscribe( data  =>  this.closeDrawer();)`

Answer (score 4):

I use trigger fuction1 (child's function) in parent component like this :)

**Component 1(child):**

```
@Component(
  selector:'com1'
)
export class Component1{
  function1(){...}
}
```

**Component 2(parent):**

```
@Component(
  selector:'com2',
  template: `<button (click)="component1.function1()"
             <com1 #component1></com1>`
)
export class Component2{
}
```

#component1 is a template variable. You can replace it with any name. (Ex: #hello1)

Comment: I have a single button on a page that has to fire functions on multiple child components at the same time. This feels wrong to do for some reason, but it works if you string the functions together in the click event as multiple statements. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the real world, scenario its not about calling a simple function but a function with a proper value. So let's dive in. This is the scenario
A user has a requirement to fire an event from his own component and also at the end he wants to call a function of another component as well. Let's say the service file is the same for both the components

componentOne.html

```
    <button (click)="savePreviousWorkDetail()" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn submit-but" type="button">
          Submit
        </button>
```

When the user clicks on the submit button he needs to call savePreviousWorkDetail() in its own component componentOne.ts and in the end he needs to call a function of another component as well. So to do that a function in a service class can be called from componentOne.ts and when that called, the function from componentTwo will be fired.

componentOne.ts

```
constructor(private httpservice: CommonServiceClass) {
  }

savePreviousWorkDetail() {
// Things to be Executed in this function

this.httpservice.callMyMethod("Niroshan");
}
```

commontServiceClass.ts

```
import {Injectable,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CommonServiceClass{

  invokeMyMethod = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  callMyMethod(params: any = 'Niroshan') {
    this.invokeMyMethod.emit(params);
  }

}
```

And Below is the componentTwo which has the function that needed to be called from componentOne. And in ngOnInit() we have to subscribe for the invoked method so when it triggers methodToBeCalled() will be called

componentTwo.ts

```
import {Observable,Subscription} from 'rxjs';


export class ComponentTwo implements OnInit {

 constructor(private httpservice: CommonServiceClass) {
  }

myMethodSubs: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    
    this.myMethodSubs = this.httpservice.invokeMyMethod.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.methodToBeCalled();
    });
    
methodToBeCalled(){
//what needs to done
}
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For unrelated components use this simple method using a shared service.

**//YourService**

```
private subject = new Subject<any>();
sendClickEvent() {
  this.subject.next();
}
getClickEvent(): Observable<any>{ 
  return this.subject.asObservable();
}
}
```

**//Component where you have button**

```
clickMe(){
this.YourServiceObj.sendClickEvent();
}

<button (click)="clickMe()">Click Me</button>
```

**//Componenet where you recieve click event**

```
    this.sharedService.getClickEvent().subscribe(()=>{
    this.doWhateverYouWant();
    }

)
```

Comment: Working. Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Lets say 1st component is DbstatsMainComponent
- 2nd component DbstatsGraphComponent.
- 1st component calling the method of 2nd

`<button (click)="dbgraph.displayTableGraph()">Graph</button>
 <dbstats-graph #dbgraph></dbstats-graph>`

Note the local variable `#dbgraph` on the child component, which the parent can use to access its methods (`dbgraph.displayTableGraph()`).

Answer (score 1):

1. Add injectable decorator to component2(or any component which have the method)

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
```

2. Inject into component1 (the component from where component2 method will be called)

```
constructor(public comp2 : component2) { }
```

3. Define method in component1 from where component2 method is called

```
method1()
{
    this.comp2.method2();
}
```

component 1 and component 2 code below.

```
import {Component2} from './Component2';

@Component({
  selector: 'sel-comp1',
  templateUrl: './comp1.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp1.scss']
})
export class Component1 implements OnInit {
  show = false;
  constructor(public comp2: Component2) { }
method1()
 {
   this.comp2.method2(); 
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'sel-comp2',
  templateUrl: './comp2.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp2.scss']
})
export class Component2 implements OnInit {
  method2()
{
  alert('called comp2 method from comp1');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

best way to call a method from another components is using "ViewContainerRef".
Actually, I had this problem myself and I tried this idea and it worked very well.

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef){}
  
  callMethod() {
     this.vcRef.createComponent(AnotherComponent).instance.myMethod();

   //updated: you have to clear the created component at the end.
   this.vcRef.clear();
  }

}
```