# Cannot import child component to parent component

Tags: angular, viewchild

I am using Angular 5.
I want to call the child component method from parent component. For this I am adding the 
import {myChildComponent} from './myChild/myChild.component'; //ERROR: Cannot find module ./myChild/myChild.component

How can I  import the child component in any other component other than app.component.ts.(here it works)

Comment: Add parent and child child component codes here

Comment: are you sure you have the right url path?

Comment: probably wrong import path

Comment: just a note, its bad practice to include components in other components

Comment: Yes when I try to add the import in app.component.ts it works!

Comment: Oh! what would be the best way to call method in child component from any other component. I was trying to use @ViewChild to call the method

Comment: @user2480755 check my answer below  , may help you out !!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call function of child component from parent component using `local variable` in Angular.

For example

```
<hello name="{{ name }}" #childOne></hello>
<p (click)='childOne.callFromParent()'>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

here `hello` is child component.

## [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqs3a7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

## Second way

```
<hello name="{{ name }}" #childOne></hello>
<button (click)='callChildFunction()'>hello</button>

@ViewChild('childOne') childOne: any;

callChildFunction() {
    this.childOne.callFromParent();
  }
```

Comment: Nice! But I am not sure how it will work in my scenario. I have two components one is master with 2 buttons and one for map-view. When I click one of the buttons in master I need to pass the marker type for map. Based on which I can draw custom markers on map. I tried passing it as parameter but seems like the value is not received on child or map-view component. Thats why I tried to call the map-view method(which changes the map marker) from master component.

Comment: May `@input/@output` trick for you