# How to call method from another component without include angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm a newbie with Angular 6.I have a few problems in call method another component.
I have 3 components like this

- app.component.ts
- com.header.ts
- app.component-user-profile.ts

In app.component.ts I include com.header.ts

```
**com.header.html**
<com-header>{{fullName}}</com-header>
**com.header.ts**
private onGetUserInfo(){
   this.fullName = "My FullName"
}
public onTest(){
  this.onGetUserInfo();
}
**app.component-user-profile.html**
<com-header>{{fullName}}</com-header><!--Without Include-->
<button (click)="onTest();">call method form com.header.ts</button>
app.component-user-profile.ts
private onTest(){
   //call method form com.header.ts
    ????
}
```

How to call method from call method form com.header.ts without include? 
 `<com-header></com-header><!--Without Include-->`

Thank you

Comment: Use event emitters or else just initialize components and call to those methods using component objects.

Comment: I'm sr,i don't understand,have you example ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37587862/6284370 you better check this post :)

Comment: Thank you.I follow this post.But I called to method,but View html not reload data