# Exporting a method from one component to another component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have defined one method in one component. I want to use that method in another component. Basically `Export` and `Import` but I don't how to do it with method.

**abc.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
export class ABCComponent {

    getUser(){
        //Some code
    }
}
```

**def.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ABCComponent } from '../../abc.component.ts';
export class DEFComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnit(){
        //I want to use getUser method here from abc.component.ts
    }
}
```

Comment: This has an answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587732/how-to-call-another-components-function-in-angular2.

Comment: @Chris this link may help u https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: @Chris my link is helpful or not ?

Comment: yeahhh thanks Ankit