# Parent function is not calling when event emit in Angular 6 after routing to a new module

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6

I created a new module in Angular 6, other than app - module.
    1. Created two components: query-bulider and query-panel.
    2. query-builder is parent component and  query-panel is child component.
    3. not able to call parent function from the child component. 
---inside query-bulider html
    
    `<query-panel (msgEvent)="recieveMsg($event)"></query-panel>`

---inside query-panel html

```
    <button class='btn btn-primary' (click)="sendMessage()">Click me</button>
```

-----inside  query-bulider component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'query-builder',
  templateUrl: './query-builder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./query-builder.component.css']
})
export class QueryBuilderComponent implements OnInit {


  submitted = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  recieveMsg(event){
    console.log('inside builder component');
  }


}
```

----------inside  query-panel component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'query-panel',
  templateUrl: './query-panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./query-panel.component.css']
})
export class QueryPanelComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() msgEvent = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.msgEvent = new EventEmitter();
  }




    sendMessage(){

       this.msgEvent.emit('Stop');
       console.log('send  message');

    }

}
```

----------------App componet html

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

---------App module---

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { QueryBuilderModule } from './component/query-builder/query-builder.module';
import { QueryBuilderComponent } from './component/query-builder/query-builder.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';


const appRoutes: Routes=[
  {
      path:'', component:QueryBuilderComponent
  }]

  export const routing= RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    QueryBuilderModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---------Query bulider module--

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ObjectBrowserComponent } from '../object-browser/object-browser.component';
import { QueryPanelComponent } from '../query-panel/query-panel.component';
import { OutputPanelComponent } from '../output-panel/output-panel.component';
import { QueryBuilderComponent } from './query-builder.component';
import { TreeViewComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-navigations';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,


  ],
  declarations: [
    QueryBuilderComponent, 
    ObjectBrowserComponent,
    QueryPanelComponent,
    OutputPanelComponent,
    TreeViewComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [QueryBuilderComponent]
})
export class QueryBuilderModule { }
```

Comment: using ViewChild parent client relationship parent can access client methods, could you try out event emitter from client to parent may be this article would be useful ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587732/how-to-call-another-components-function-in-angular2

Comment: Is your button from query panel displayed ? Do you have your `send message` log ?

Comment: Remove `ngOnInit` function from QueryPanelComponent.

Comment: @Cyril yes, it is in log..

Answer (score 0):

> Your code is working fine except the following in your `QueryPanelComponent`-

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.msgEvent = new EventEmitter();    // remove this
}
```

As you already declared an Output parameter `msgEvent` as an instance of `EventEmitter`, **you should remove it from `ngOnInit()`**

See it live ***[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-child-parent-comm)***.

Answer (score 0):

you have extra initialaztion of event Emitter

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.msgEvent = new EventEmitter();
  }
```

remove this and it will work