# Execute function in other component with no parent child relationship in angular 8

Tags: angular

Execute function in other component without parent child relationship in angular 8. Demo code is given url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bex9hp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call another components function in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587732/how-to-call-another-components-function-in-angular2)

Comment: Input Output not helpful as no connection between two component, so above link is not helpful

Comment: Please look at the complete answer before jumping to conclusions. In the last section you will see how two components can interact via services for unrelated components.

Comment: If possible please go through the link I have mentioined  to understand

Comment: Where should the `TwoComponent` be rendered? What's its place in DOM hierarchy? Also: you have two components with the same selector, `<my-app>`.

Comment: my-app duplicate was a mistake, I want to click func2 from TwoComponent when click on proceed button

Comment: If you don't intend to put `TwoComponent` somewhere inside your `AppComponent`, then, first, using `ViewChild` is a mistake, and two, use a service, not an another component.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the TwoComponent Reference anyway because if it is not constructed any of its functions will not be called.

change app.component.html

```
<my-app-two #TwoComponent></my-app-two>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="func1()">Proceed</button>
```

And in TS file change @ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('TwoComponent', {static: false}) TwoComponent: TwoComponent;
```

Comment: Why `static: false`?

Comment: @Dinesh Shekhawat thanks, but in your example there is parent child relationship

Comment: Like I said even if you avoid a parent child relationship and try to perform a sibling-sibling relationship the component declaration has to be given in the html

Comment: I was trying with @ViewChild but it is not helpful, Can u  help if it is possible with observable

Comment: Please update your code with the changes I have suggested and then see if it's working. I have tested the same on your stackblitz example.