# Why won't mat-drawer respond to `.toggle` when it's called from outside its own component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using `mat-drawer` to add sidenav to a page. I'm putting the drawer into a `side-nav-container` component that will be common to all pages so that each page can have the following structure:

```
<!-- a page in my app -->
<app-side-nav-container #container>

  <!-- Button to trigger side-nav to open or close -->
  <button type="button" mat-button (click)="container.tryToggle()">
    Toggle nav (from an element on the page)
  </button>

  Content in the rest of the page

</app-side-nav-container>
```

In the code above I'm triggering the toggle behaviour by calling a `.tryToggle()` method which exists on the `side-nav-container` element. I've used the `#container` notation to create a reference to the container component. This is that container component:

```
export class SideNavContainerComponent {

  @ViewChild('drawer')
  public drawer?: MatDrawer

  public tryToggle() :void {
    console.log('Toggling. drawer.opened=' + this.drawer?.opened)
    this.drawer?.toggle()
  }
}
```

#### .tryToggle() is accessible from the projected content but won't trigger the drawer

When I click "Toggle nav" in the projected content, the `console.log` call works as expected and prints the value of `this.drawer?.opened`. This value alternates between true and false.

[image]

However the drawer doesn't work. It won't open or close. It's very peculiar. It's not that the drawer is out of scope - it's in scope and I can print it into the console. It just doesn't open or close.

#### .tryToggle works when called by an element inside the container component

If I call exactly the same method but triggered by  button inside the the parent component then it works.

```
// side-nav-container.html
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container" autosize>
  
  <mat-drawer #drawer mode="side">
    <p>Sidenav content </p>
  </mat-drawer>

  <div class="body-of-page">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>

  <!-- additional button to test behaviour... --> 
  <button type="button" mat-button (click)="tryToggle()">
    Toggle sidenav (this works)
  </button>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: A similar question is already been asked -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587732/how-to-call-another-components-function-in-angular2

Comment: This is a slightly different question. As far as I can tell, I've got no problem calling the method on the parent. I have access. the problem is that even with access, the drawer isn't responding to the method that is successfully called in the parent

Comment: Also this suffers from the same problem whether you trigger the opening via a service, an event or using the direct methodology above. I just can't get the sidenav to open unless I click in the actual nav container component

Comment: Try to call this.drawer?.toggle() inside setTimeout

Comment: @Chellappanவ - excellent suggestion. I kept considering that but then not doing it for some reason. It still fails though. I tried it on multiple delays one after the other and using `sidenav.open()` to be sure I wasn't accidentally toggling the wrong way. Still nothing though

Comment: Does your SideNavContainerComponent component use onpush change detection strategy?

Comment: Oh my god Chellappan. I was literally just coming back here to say that I'd fixed it by switching the change strategy from `OnPush`. I'm SO impressed that you figured this out in abstract. I did get there before you but I've also been working on this all day. Please can you at least put this into an answer so that I can give you some more points.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem because of `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

I had to do an explicit call to `markForCheck` on the `ChangeDetectorRef`.