# Can we can access all methods from one component to another

Tags: angular

I have two components, Among those two, one component is acting as a provider. how we can access all methods from component A to its provider.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { NewParcelModal } from './new-parcel-modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-new-parcels',
  templateUrl: './add-new-parcels.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-new-parcels.component.scss'],
  providers: [NewParcelModal, MomentDateFormatter]
})
export class AddNewParcelsComponent implements OnInit {
 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getWindowsProperties();
    this.createControls();
    this.addNewParcelForm.patchValue(this.modalInfo);
    this.getNoticeTypeList();
  }
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    this.getWindowsProperties();
  }
 
  createControls() {
    this.addNewParcelForm = this.formBuilder.group(this.newParcelModal.parcelInfo)
  }
  getSurveyTypes() {
    return { test: 'test' };
  }
}
```

Provider component

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { bind } from "@angular/core/src/render3";
import { FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { DISABLED } from "@angular/forms/src/model";
import { CONSTANTS } from "src/app/common/constants";

@Injectable()
export class NewParcelModal {
    constructor() { }
    parcelInfo = {       
        royaltyrate: new FormControl(null),
        percentinterest: new FormControl(null)    
        };

}
```

I am using `NewParcelModal` as provider in the component `AddNewParcelsComponent`

Problem: Not able to aceess `getSurveyTypes` method from `AddNewParcelsComponent` in the `NewParcelModal` component.

Comment: check out this may be help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587732/how-to-call-another-components-function-in-angular2

Comment: Typically, one shares functionality between components via services, not by making a component a provider. [Angular's documentation on providers has all of the examples using services or plain objects and classes](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#dependency-providers). You can have one component be a parent of another component, you can have inheritance between components (although this is discouraged), but I've never head of using a component as a provider.

Comment: Angular is not react, you don't need to use components to share data/call functions. Use functions, state, or input/output and tree structure of the components. Services are recommended though

Comment: using service fulfilled my requirement. @HereticMonkey Thanks for detailed info

Answer (score 1):

You can use services for sharing functions/data in between multiple components. Please refer https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4 this documentation for further details.