# pass values from one component to another component in angular 13

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-ui-router, angular13, angular-data

I have an array of values in one component, I want to pass the data from one component to another component in angular 13.i'm new in this. Here I have a search box. I want to show the search result in another component of angular page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call another components function in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587732/how-to-call-another-components-function-in-angular2)

Comment: Yes, this is not an specific issue of Angular 13. It's data binding of Angular. See https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding