# How to call a function from another component and use it in HTML/another component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to call a function that draws a diagram (the data in the diagram is from an API call) from another component to the main HTML. There was a similar question asked here but It didn't help me.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { RestService } from '../rest.service';
import { Chart,registerables  } from 'chart.js';

@Component({
selector: 'app',
templateUrl: './humidity.html'
})

export class Humidity
{
result:any;
stamp: any;
name:any;
measure:any;

constructor(private http: RestService)
{
Chart.register(...registerables);
}

    ngOnInit()
    {
      this.http.getMeasurments().then((data)=>{
        this.result=data;
        console.log(this.result);
    
        this.name = this.result.series[0].name;
        this.measure = this.result.series[0].data;
        this.stamp = this.result.labels;
        this.drawChart123();
    
      });
    }
    drawChart123()
    {
        new Chart ('canvas', {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            labels: this.stamp,
            datasets: [{
                label: this.name,
                data: this.measure,
                pointStyle: 'crossRot',
                backgroundColor: [
                    'DeepSkyBlue',
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'DeepSkyBlue'
                    
                ],
                borderWidth: 3
            }]
        },
        options: 
        {
          elements:
          {
            point:
            {
              borderWidth: 0,
              radius: 3,
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
            }
          },
          
        }
        }) 
      }

}
```

The code above is from the Humidity component that draws the diagram. The Humidity component has a template HTML that contains only 1 div with canvas inside it.
Another problem here is that when i try to console.log the result from the API I'm not getting the data from the API.

```
getMeasurments()
{
let url = '...';
return this.http.get(url).toPromise().then((data)=\>{
return data
});
}
```

The code above Is what I use to get the data from the API.

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { RestService } from './rest.service';
import { Chart,registerables  } from 'chart.js';
import { NgIf } from '@angular/common';
**import { Humidity } from './test/humidity';**

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: \['./app.component.css'\],
\*\* providers: \[Humidity\]\*\*
})
export class AppComponent
{

constructor(**private comp: Humidity**,private http: RestService)
{
Chart.register(...registerables);
}

**public test() {
this.comp.drawChart123();
}**
```

The code above is a small part of my main component.

```
<div class="name" (click)="test()">
                Humidity
                <div class="value">
                    <ng-container *ngIf="moisture; else noValue">

                        {{this.moisture}}%

                    </ng-container>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
```

The code above Is where I tried calling the function in the HTML.

I made a function that draws the chart for "Humidity" but there are more measurments and If I make another function that draws a diagram an error in the console pops up saying that I have to delete the canvas to use it again. Therefore i'm trying to split each measurment and each should have their own canvas (if that's possible).

The text in bold i saw and tried from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587732/how-to-call-another-components-function-in-angular2).

I also tried watching tutorials on youtube or in websites but they didn't really helped.

My goal is when "Humidity" is clicked a diagram should be drawn and the contents of the diagram should be from the API call.

I am new to Angular so any tips and advices will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Before, you need to use Angular version of chart.js here :
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts

you will be able to generate your graphics more easily.

if you want to share graphics data, use service or store, not in component.