# Subscription of an event-emitter is not working

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to build an angular app containing two sibling components - Welcome & Questions. The Welcome template has a textbox for username and I want to display that username in my Question component template. For this, I have written a service to communicate between these two sibling components. Here are my codes -

**username.service.ts**

```
      export class UsernameService {
         name = new EventEmitter<string>();
      }
```

**welcome.component.ts**

```
    export class WelcomeComponent {
      username: string = '';
      @ViewChild('username') usernameInput: ElementRef;
      constructor(private unameService: UsernameService){}
      onStartQuiz(){
         this.username = this.usernameInput.nativeElement.value;//the value is correct      
         this.unameService.name.emit(this.username);
       }
    }
```

**question.component.ts**

```
    export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {
       username: string = '';
       constructor(private unameService: UsernameService) { }
       ngOnInit(): void {
          this.unameService.name.subscribe((data) => {
          console.log(data); //This is not getting printed
        });
       }
      }
```

Inside subscribe, nothing is getting printed. I also tried using Subjects but then also the result is same. I have also provided the service in **app.module** .I am not able to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Did you register your service as a singleton? Otherwise, your two components will have different instances. You can achieve this by adding `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})` decorator above your service.

Comment: yes @Eldar, I have done this as well. Still it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Event emitters are not used in that way. If you want to communicate through a service, you need to use observables to subscribe to. Bear in mind you also need to unsubscribe from them when you destroy the component to prevent memory leaks.

**username.service.ts**

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

export class UsernameService {

  private name = new Subject<string>();

  public name$ = this.name.asObservable();

  // Method to ensure the private name property can be set by the components.
  setName(name: string) {
    this.name.next(name);
  }
}
```

**welcome.component.ts**

```
export class WelcomeComponent {

  @ViewChild('username')
  public usernameInput: ElementRef;

  public username: string = '';

  constructor(
    private usernameService: UsernameService,
  ) { }

  onStartQuiz(){
    this.username = this.usernameInput.nativeElement.value;    
    this.usernameService.setName(this.username);
  }
}
```

**question.component.ts**

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {

  private nameSubscription: Subscription;
  
  public username: string = '';

  constructor(
    private usernameService: UsernameService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.nameSubscription = this.usernameService.name$.subscribe(name => {
      this.username = name;
      console.log(this.username);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.nameSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

You can accomplish the same with event emitters, if **welcome.component.ts** and **question.component.ts** are truly sibling components (i.e. if they have the same parent component). There is an excellent post detailing communication between components which you can find here: [How to call another components function in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587732/how-to-call-another-components-function-in-angular2).

Comment: Actually the problem was not using Subjects or EventEmitters. The issue was that Welcome and Question Component was not there in the view at the same time. When I am giving the username in the text box in welcome component, the question component is not there in the view yet. Thats why it's not able to catch the subscription. What I did is storing the value of username in a property in my service and then used it in the Question component. This is one of the solutions. Another solution is using Behavioral Subject.