# How to reload view without reload whole page?

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular2-components

I have three components. A parent and two children.
One child (the add-friend) wants to update the parents view. So i created the method `receiveReloadFriendLists()`.
I let the method write me an info into the console. So this works fine.
But the view don't gets updated. Now there should be a list of friends. What do i need to do for this?
I don't want to reload the page, because there is an animation running. Which would get killed.
I am sure i missed something in the parent or did something wrong.

I would be happy for help or links to a solution.
I followed the first answer [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587732/how-to-call-another-components-function-in-angular2)
But it didn't fullfil my question.

**Parent:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-friends',
  templateUrl: './friends.component.html'
})
export class FriendsComponent implements OnInit {
  requested$: Observable<RelationResponse[]>;
  requested: RelationResponse[] = [];

  constructor(
    private store: Store,
    private router: Router,
    private appStore: Store<AppState>,
    private _fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.requested$ = this.store.select(selectRequestedRelationResponse);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getRequestedRelations();
  }

  private getRequestedRelations() {
    this.store.dispatch(invokeFindRequestedRelations({
        userId: StorageUtil.getUserId(),
        relationStatusRequest: RelationStatusRequest.REQUESTED
      })
    );

    this.appStore.pipe(select(selectAppState)).subscribe((appState) => {
        if (ApiUtil.ifApiStatusIsSuccessReset(appState, this.appStore)) {
          this.requested$.subscribe((relationResponses) => {
            this.requested = relationResponses;
          })
        }
      }
    );
  }

  receiveReloadFriendLists() {
    console.log("reload");
    this.getRequestedRelations();
  }

}
```

**Parent html:**

```
  <app-add-friend (reloadRelationsEvent)="receiveReloadFriendLists()" class="p-0"></app-add-friend>

  <app-relation-list class="p-0"
                     [show]=hasFriendRequests()
                     showHeadline="Friend requests"
                     noShowHeadline="No Friend requests"
                     [relations]="requested"
                     [enableAccept]="true"
                     [enableBlock]="true"
                     [enableDelete]="true"></app-relation-list>
```

**Child - Add Friend**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-friend',
  templateUrl: './add-friend.component.html'
})
export class AddFriendComponent {

  @Output() reloadRelationsEvent = new EventEmitter<void>();
  @ViewChild('sendFriendRequestCallout') sendFriendRequestCallout!: CalloutComponent;

  addFriendForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder,
              private store: Store) {
    this.addFriendForm = this.createAddFriendForm();
  }

  public createAddFriendForm(): FormGroup {
    ...
  }

  sendFriendRequest() {
    ....
  }

  reloadFriendLists() {
    this.reloadRelationsEvent.emit();
  }

}
```

**Child - Show Friends**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-relation-list',
  templateUrl: './relation-list.component.html'
})
export class RelationListComponent {

  @Input() show: boolean = false;
  @Input() showHeadline: string = '';
  @Input() noShowHeadline: string = '';
  @Input() relations: RelationResponse[] = [];
  @Input() enableAccept: boolean = false;
  @Input() enableBlock: boolean = false;
  @Input() enableDelete: boolean = false;

...

}
```

**Child - Show Friends - html**

```
<div class="card p-3 mt-3">
  <h5 class="card-title">{{ showHeadline }}</h5>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let relation of relations">
    {{relation.contactUsername }}
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not accessing the state directly from the child - show friends? You can then omit whole input/output communication.

Comment: @mat.hudak I am new in angular. So i am sorry. but i dont understand how to do this. Do you have a link, i can read about it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a very strange design in your code which is worth refactoring. You're making some crazy subscriptions and trying to filter them using `Util` functions. And you don't care about unsubscribing. This means that your subscriptions are alive even after the component was destroyed and this could lead to some strange errors.

Using a [filter](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/filter) operator and [async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe you can achieve both things while simplifying the code and making it less error prone.

```typescript
export class FriendsComponent implements OnInit {
  requested$: Observable<RelationResponse[]>;
  //requested: RelationResponse[] = []; // Not needed

  constructor(
    private store: Store,
    private router: Router,
    private appStore: Store<AppState>,
    private _fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Don't subscribe within the component, just assign the observable to 
    // the variable and use it directly in the Template
    this.requested$ = this.store.select(selectRequestedRelationResponse).pipe(
      // Use rxjs filter operator to only care about updates which pass the condition (as you did within subscribe)
      filter(() => ApiUtil.ifApiStatusIsSuccessReset(appState, this.appStore))
    );
    this.receiveReloadFriendLists();
  }

  receiveReloadFriendLists() {
    // Use this method only to dispatch an action
    console.log("reload");
    this.store.dispatch(invokeFindRequestedRelations({
      userId: StorageUtil.getUserId(),
      relationStatusRequest: RelationStatusRequest.REQUESTED
    });
  }

}
```

And then one small change in the parent HTML, assign the value to relations with `requested$` Observable using the `async` pipe. This way you don't need to worry about manually unsubscribing (which you didn't do in your code)

```typescript
<app-add-friend (reloadRelationsEvent)="receiveReloadFriendLists()" class="p-0"></app-add-friend>

<app-relation-list class="p-0"
  [show]=hasFriendRequests()
  showHeadline="Friend requests"
  noShowHeadline="No Friend requests"
  [relations]="requested$ | async"
  [enableAccept]="true"
  [enableBlock]="true"
  [enableDelete]="true"
>
</app-relation-list>
```

To explain what I meant with my question in the comments. You can take a slice of the store directly in the child component and then you won't need to pass the values up and down between children and parent. Same applies to the
`invokeFindRequestedRelations` action. It can be dispatched from the child directly.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-relation-list',
  templateUrl: './relation-list.component.html'
})
export class RelationListComponent implements OnInit {
  relations$!: Observable<RelationResponse[]>;

  @Input() show: boolean = false;
  @Input() showHeadline: string = '';
  @Input() noShowHeadline: string = '';
  // relations are no longer needed as an Input
  @Input() enableAccept: boolean = false;
  @Input() enableBlock: boolean = false;
  @Input() enableDelete: boolean = false;

  constructor(private appStore: Store<AppState>) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.relations$ = this.store.select(selectRequestedRelationResponse)
    // And once again, use it with the async pipe
  }
}
```

See what suits you better or try both approaches to get better understanding of it.

Comment: thank you very much for your time and your answer.
Yes i found out, that there is a problem with not to unsubscribe. I already ajusted this.

But nevertheless i appreciate your suggestions and will try it in my application. This is lookes like the code will be much more clear to read.